# Remove lines from csv if duplicate value in column

Tags: python, parsing, csv

i am trying to write csv parser so if i have the same name in the name column i will delete the second name's line. For example:

```
['CSE_MAIN\\LC-CSEWS61', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-04-18-192446'],
['CSE_MAIN\\IT-Laptop12', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-03-28-144236'],
['CSE_MAIN\\LC-CSEWS61', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-03-28-144236']]
```

I need that the last line will be deleted because it has the same name as the first one.

What i wrote is:

```
file2 = str(sys.argv[2])
print ("The first file is:" + file2)
reader2 = csv.reader (open(file2))
with open("result2.csv",'wb') as result2:
    wtr2= csv.writer( result2 )
    for r in reader2:
        wtr2.writerow( (r[0], r[6], r[9] ))
newreader2 = csv.reader (open("result2.csv"))
sortedlist2 = sorted(newreader2, key=lambda col: col[2] , reverse = True)
for i in range(len(sortedlist2)):
    for j in range(len(sortedlist2)-1):
        if (sortedlist2[i][0] == sortedlist2[j+1][0] and sortedlist2[i][1]!=sortedlist2[j+1][1]):
            if(sortedlist2[i][1]>sortedlist2[j+1][1]):
                del sortedlist2[i][0-2]
            else:
                del sortedlist2[j+1][0-2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Two possible solutions are **1)** store the column in a `dictionary/Java set` and do a lookup before you write a row **2)** sort the data on the column and only write the row if the column changes

Comment: Can you confirm that the code functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate multiple times over the file. You just need to keep a record of all names seen so far and skip lines with already seen names. This takes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ additional memory, but only \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time.

It assumes that the file is already in the right order (i.e. you always want to keep the first time a name appears). Otherwise you would have to sort it first by time (also included further down).

This is particularly easy to implement, because it already exists as an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

> ```
> from itertools import filterfalse
>
> def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
>     "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
>     # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
>     # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
>     seen = set()
>     seen_add = seen.add
>     if key is None:
>         for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
>             seen_add(element)
>             yield element
>     else:
>         for element in iterable:
>             k = key(element)
>             if k not in seen:
>                 seen_add(k)
>                 yield element
> ```

In this case you can use it like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

with open(sys.argv[2]) as in_file, open("result2.csv", "w") as out_file:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(in_file), csv.writer(out_file)
    for row in unique_everseen(reader, key=itemgetter(0)):
        writer.writerow((row[0], row[6], row[9]))
```

If you do need to sort it, you can just add it before the filtering:

```
for row in unique_everseen(sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(9)), key=itemgetter(0)):
```

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is basically just this function:

```
def itemgetter(i):
    return lambda col: col[i]
```

---

If you always have to sort anyway, you can sort by both name and date and use the slightly easier recipe `unique_justseen`, which has basically no memory overhead:

> ```
> from itertools import groupby
>
> def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
>     "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
>     # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
>     # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
>     return map(next, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
> ```

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

with open(sys.argv[2]) as in_file, open("result2.csv", "w") as out_file:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(in_file), csv.writer(out_file)
    sorted_rows = sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(0, 9), reverse=True)
    for row in unique_justseen(sorted_rows, key=itemgetter(0)):
        writer.writerow((row[0], row[6], row[9]))
```